How to include nested 'Document' objects in ElasticSearch search results in Go
I'm working on a Go project where I use ElasticSearch to search and retrieve data. I have the following function SearchSimple that performs a search query:
func (es *adSpecializedMachinery) SearchSimple(ctx context.Context, match string) ([]model.AdSpecializedMachinery, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    query := map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "multi_match": map[string]interface{}{
                "query":     match,
                "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                "fields": []interface{}{
                    "name",
                    "description",
                },
            },
        },
    }

    if err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(query); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error encoding query: %w", err)
    }

    res, err := es.client.Search(
        es.client.Search.WithContext(ctx),
        es.client.Search.WithIndex(indexAdSm),
        es.client.Search.WithBody(&buf),
        es.client.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
        es.client.Search.WithPretty(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    if res.IsError() {
        var e map[string]interface{}
        if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&e); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error parsing the response body: %w", err)
        } else {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("[%s] %s: %s", res.Status(), e["error"].(map[string]interface{})["type"], e["error"].(map[string]interface{})["reason"])
        }
    }

    ads, err := parseHint[model.AdSpecializedMachinery](res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse body: %w", err)
    }

    return ads, nil
}

And the models:
type AdSpecializedMachinery struct {
    ID          int                           `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time                     `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time                     `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt   gorm.DeletedAt                `json:"deleted_at" gorm:"index" swaggertype:"string"`
    UserID      int                           `json:"user_id"`
    User        User                          `json:"user" gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    BrandID     int                           `json:"brand_id"`
    Brand       Brand                         `json:"brand" gorm:"foreignKey:BrandID"`
    TypeID      int                           `json:"type_id"`
    Type        Type                          `json:"type" gorm:"foreignKey:TypeID"`
    CityID      int                           `json:"city_id"`
    City        City                          `json:"city"`
    Price       float64                       `json:"price"` //Цена за час работы
    Name        string                        `json:"name"`
    Description string                        `json:"description"`
    CountRate   int                           `json:"count_rate"`
    Rating      float64                       `json:"rating"`
    UrlDocument []string                      `json:"url_foto" gorm:"-"`
    Document    []Document                    `json:"-" gorm:"many2many:ad_specialized_machineries_documents;"`
    Address     string                        `json:"address"`
    Latitude    *float64                      `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude   *float64                      `json:"longitude"`
    Params      AdSpecializedMachinerieParams `json:"params"`
}

type Document struct {
    ID              int            `json:"id" gorm:"<-:create;primarykey;"`
    UserID          int            `json:"-"  gorm:"<-:create;varchar(50)"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time      `json:"-" gorm:"<-:create;"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time      `json:"-" gorm:"<-:update"`
    DeletedAt       gorm.DeletedAt `json:"-" gorm:"<-:delete;"`
    Title           string         `form:"title,omitempty" json:"title,omitempty" gorm:"varchar(2000)"`
    Extension       string         `json:"-" gorm:"varchar(10);<-:create"`
    Size            int64          `json:"-" gorm:"number;<-:create;"`
    Type            string         `json:"-" gorm:"varchar(255);<-:create"`
    Path            uuid.UUID      `json:"-" gorm:"<-:create;type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    ShareLink       string         `json:"shareLink,omitempty" gorm:"-:all"`
    RequestContent  io.ReadSeeker  `gorm:"-:all" json:"-"`
    ResponseContent []byte         `gorm:"-:all" json:"-"`
}

The problem:
When I run SearchSimple, the returned AdSpecializedMachinery objects have an empty Document field. I need the search results to include the associated Document objects.

json:"-" is the tag given. Remove this and use json:"doc" instead, assuming you get the ES docs in a "doc":[list of documents] format.
